# Gitkraken cannot connect to any provider

Tags: gitlab, connection, gitkraken

I want to clone a repo from Gitlab using Gitkraken. When clicking connect to Gitlab it says connecting for 0.5s and then reports Not Connected. The activity log says:

[16:47:23] Request OAuth token from GitLab: started.

[16:47:23] Request OAuth token from GitLab: [object Event]

[16:47:23] Request OAuth token from GitLab: finished with errors.

Does anyone know what is going on? It works with the same user on another computer and other network. Can it be a network issu? The company network is really strict with everything going in and out and manipulates the packages.

(It is the same issue with Gitlab too. So nothing todo with the git-provider)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?  Because I am experiencing the same thing now, but when trying to connect to GitHub

Comment: No i gave up on GitKraken.